# Regex - Min 7 Chars, at Least 1 letter, 1 number, anything else except no whitespace

Tags: regex

I am trying to expand this regex, currently it validates a password, ensuring at least one letter, one number, minimum seven charcaters and allows any other characters. I need to modify it to disallow whitespace.

`/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{7,}$/`

I have been unable to modify to work as required

Comment: Try `^(?=[^\s\d]*\d)(?=[^\sa-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])\S{7,}$` See https://regex101.com/r/7pafiE/1

Comment: Paul, I'm curious, did my modification of your regex work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the regex you have is pretty close. Add a beginning of the line anchor (`^`) and replace the dots (`.`) with `\S` to match on any non-whitespace character:

```
^(?=\S*\d)(?=\S*[a-zA-Z])\S{7,}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/x2Td1u/1)